# how to get today ,past or future date data from room database in android?

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

**how to get today ,past or future date data from room database in android?**

> below is the model class and there is a ***task_date*** field I have taken with Date object.

**Model class**

```
    @Entity
data class Task(
    @PrimaryKey
    val tid: Long?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "task_date") val task_date: Date?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "task_hour") val task_hour: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "task_minute") val task_minute: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "task_cat") val task_cat: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "task_repeat") val task_repeat: String?,
) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Task(tid=$tid, title=$title, task_date=$task_date, task_hour=$task_hour, task_minute=$task_minute, task_cat=$task_cat, task_repeat=$task_repeat)"
    }
}
```

**Below There is query code**

> i am passing **Date()** today date to get today inserted data list

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM task WHERE task_date = :targetDate")
fun getUpcomingTask(targetDate: Date): List<Task>
```

**Data insertion code is here**

```
  val task = Task(
                        Utils.getUniqueId(),
                        bindingActivity.inputTaskTitle.text.toString(),
                        Date(),
                        selectedHour, selectedMinute,
                        bindingActivity.mySpinnerDropdown.text.toString(),
                        Constant.REPEAT.NONE
                    )
```

**Converter Class**

```
class Converters {

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Date? {
        return value?.let { Date(it) }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date?): Long? {
        return date?.time
    }

}
```

**And the final one DataBase class**

```
 @Database(entities = [Task::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun taskDao(): TaskDao
}
```

> I have shown the code implementation I never worked with date object
> so need your help to learn this date implementation  Moreover , I also
> want to retrieve data like upcoming data and past data .Please also
> give your valuable advice to learn more with date

.

**Thank You.**

Comment: I would use Long to represent a date in the database (Millis since epoch UTC). Much easier to compare and to convert to and from other formats. It’s pretty messy to use three columns just to store a single time.

Comment: @Tenfour04 please cinsider task_date column other two hour and minute are for different purpose

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with exactly what is being stored and passed due to the conversion of the date to a long.

That is the long is accurate down to a millisecond, so when query for tasks that equals the "date" it doesn't know that you only want the date part so it will be virtually impossible to get a task of the very millisecond.

Consider the following data (based upon using your code) for 3 tasks, it will look like:-

[image]

- ignore all but the task_date column
- ALL 3 rows were inserted immediately after each other at 14:10 on 2022-07-08, yet they all have different values as the value includes the milliseconds.

So `SELECT * FROM task WHERE task_date = :targetDate` will not probably never get any records.

**Todays**

However consider this query `SELECT * FROM task WHERE task_date / (1000 /* drop millis*/ * 60 /* drop seconds */ * 60 /* drop minutes */ * 24 /* drop hours */) = :targetDate / 86400000`

- Note comments explain how the 86400000 was derived (it's the same value applied to both sides of the comparison). i.e. stripping of every but the date from the stored long value.

**Future and Past**

For Future and the past it wouldn't matter about the milliseconds so you could then use `SELECT * FROM task WHERE task_date > :targetDate` (for Future) and `SELECT * FROM task WHERE task_date < :targetDate` (for past)

Comment: Yes ,The date object storing value in millisecond  so equal query will never be done . I too realized this later . so I m storing date   this way **GregorianCalendar(year,month,date).time** .  and this is working now for all the operation  Like  **equal,><**.  And If u have any other better way to store and retrieve data **Please Suggest**

Comment: @unknown best is really an opinion. e.g. most efficient is to stores as a long without millis (unless needed), but for convenience sortable date format all depends and what you want to do and also where. If within SQLite then for time (down to second) then YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss is easy to work with the date time functions (see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). Long needs to use the unixepoch modifier if delving into things such as day of the week, week of the year. You can do a great deal within SQLite but not necessarily suit Room's expectations (e.g. possibly more POJO's)